# Pagemethods in Chrome executed at the end of function

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, pagemethods

I use pagemethods in my asp.net page to retrieve a value from database for use in my javascript function.
In client side I use this code :

```
var email;
function OnSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) 
{ 
  email=result;
}
function OnError(error, userContext, methodName) 
{ 
  if (error != null) 
  { 
    alert(error.get_message()); 
  } 
}
function GetValue()
{
  PageMethods.GetCustomerEmail(id,OnSuccess,OnError);
  var val=prompt("Insert the value.",email); 
  if (!(val == null))
  { 
    ...some code..
  }
}
```

I've tried in Internet Explorer and Firefox and all works correctly.
In chrome the PageMethods works but is executed at the end of the function, in this case the value of the 'email' field is always null.
What's the difference betweeen Chrome and the other browers?
How can I resolve this situation?

Comment: Can you use the chrome developer tools, or use Firebug lite, to grab the request and see what the request and response looks like?  That will give you a clue.

Comment: I did the debug of the web application with Chrome developer tools. The PageMethods instruction is simply executed after the end of the function. Any helps?? Why in Firefox and in IE it's works??

Comment: OK, I'm really confused as to your approach, as I look back through it.  Why are you prompting the user for the email, but are overlaying the email with whatever comes back from the web service?  The problem is in chrome the web service is taking some time to respond, most likely.  However, when you deploy this up to the web server, the web response will take much more time to pull the email down, so you'll start getting that error.

Comment: I did this operation because I want the email field precompiled (getting the data from database), but I want leave at the user the opportunity to change the email address. Do you think when i will deploy on production web server I'll get the error in all browser? Do you know other solutions to my problem? Thanks for your support.

Comment: I'll say it this way; the web method will never finish before you display it to the user in the prompt.  If that is your goal, you need to put the prompt in the success callback.